# How to read strings containing newline characters in Shell?

Tags: shell, testing

I would like to write a small automatic testing program using the Bourne Shell scripting language.

I need to test my `red-black_tree.c` program and for the input `1 3 2` must be the following output:

```
2,blk( ) 
1,red(2) 3,red(2) 
Current tree height is 2.
```

I know what a similar script for comparing integers should look like, so I tried to write a new one based on this knowledge:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#                                   test.sh

while read -r input expect_output ; do
    act_output=`echo "$input" | ./red-black_tree`
    if [ "$expect_output" != "$act_output" ]; then
        echo TEST "$input" FAILED: expected "$expect_output", got "$act_output"
    else
        echo OK
    fi  
done <<END
    "1 3 2" "\n2,blk( ) \n1,red(2) 3,red(2) \nCurrent tree height is 2.\n"
END
```

Of course it doesn't work as I expected it to  (the actual output of ./red-black_tree program signals that we have in our input something except space symbols and numbers):

```
~/c/red-black_tree$ ./test.sh
TEST "1 FAILED: expected 3 2" "
2,blk( ) 
1,red(2) 3,red(2) 
Current tree height is 2.
", got The string contains incorrect symbols.Please repeat your input.
```

So my question is how can I possibly read and compare different strings (especially containing newline symbols) in Shell?

Comment: I would write the expected output into a file, and then compare the output from your program to the content of this file, using `diff` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd keep the input and the corresponding expected output in separate arrays. This means you use bash not sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=()
expected=()

# test 1
input+=("1 3 2")
expected+=( $'\n2,blk( ) \n1,red(2) 3,red(2) \nCurrent tree height is 2.' )

# define other tests ...

# execute them

for idx in "${!input[@]}"; do
    actual=$(./red-black_tree <<< "${input[idx]}")
    if [[ "${expected[idx]}" != "$actual" ]]; then
        printf 'TEST "%s" FAILED: expected "%q", got "%q"\n' \
          "$input" \
          "${expected[idx]}" \
          "$actual"
    else
        echo OK
    fi  
done
```

Notes:

- command substitution (using `$(...)` or backticks) strips any trailing newlines, so don't include them in your expected output
- I've used [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
I understand that `!input[@]` returns array indexes values, but how exactly does this command work? What does it "tell" computer to execute?
Is it possible for the script to print real newlines and not `\n` in error messages?

Comment: I've found `!input[@]` description in the `bash` man page: "It is possible to obtain the keys (indices) of an array as well as  the values.   ${!name[@]} and ${!name[*]} expand to the indices assigned in array variable name." It doesn't say how the command works at the basic level, well, never mind.

Comment: As for printing real newlines in error messages, it's enough to use `%b` in `printf`.